# GRS Test in R with robust residuals

Tags: asset-pricing, fama-french

I'm testing certain asset pricing factor models  (e.g. Fama and French 3 factor model) and want to check if the alphas of my time series regressions are jointly zero.

Most papers use the Gibbons, Ross, Shanken (1989) Test to do so.

I buildt the test by myself in R, but I want to do it with robust residuals. How do I get them, corrected for heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation with e.g. Newey West?

This is how my regressions looks like:

```
FF3 <- lm(Excess_Return ~ RMRF + SMB + HML)
```

If I do:

```
FF3_corrected <- coeftest(FF3, vcov = NeweyWest)
```

Then R just shows me the corrected coefficients, but I need the corrected residuals...

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you might be aware of using the additional option  ‚prewhite = FALSE‘ in the coeftest function to get the original Newey/West (1987) standard errors.

Comment: Good Point, thanks!

Comment: Btw, what do you mean when you ask for corrected *residuals*? Point estimates of coefficients (and thus of residuals) remain exactly the same, whether you correct for robust standard errors or not.

Comment: But if I want to calculate R^2 of my model. Then I get missleading results, no?

Comment: Actually not - the residuals remain numerically exactly the same. It is just the standard deviation (standard error in this context) of the estimated regression coefficients that change.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

Load the sandwich package, which is used for correcting covariance matrices.

```
library(sandwich)
```

Run the model.

```
FF3 <- lm(Excess_Return ~ RMRF + SMB + HML)
```

Obtain the NeweyWest-corrected covariance matrix. Change the "lag" argument if you have a specific lag structure in mind.

```
rcovmatrix <- NeweyWest(FF3)
```

The corrected standard errors are the square root of the diagonal of this matrix:

```
rstderrors <- sqrt(diag(rcovmatrix))
rstderrors
```

Comment: Sorry, but I need the corrected residuals, not the standard errors...

Comment: Alright, sorry, I misunderstood.